How can I make Windows 10 stop asking me to confirm my login for everything, everyday?
A few months back, I switched the login used for Minecraft and the Microsoft store for my son's (in order to check if it was working since his Minecraft was crashing). I then switched back to my regular account (the same as the windows session/user).
However, since I did this, Windows products seem to have a hard time remembering me. OneDrive, Defender, the Xbox app, they all ask me to log in, about every day. Mind you, it is not fully forgotten, my account is there, sometimes on its own, sometimes next to the other account I used a few months back, when it asks me to log in.


Is there a way to make it keep the login for longer periods? It never used to log me off before I tried the second account.
Also, is there a way to remove the other account from the "remembered" accounts? Maybe having only one account would save on the confusion.

Open Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts\Manage Accounts and remove the unneeded account.
